# LINQ instead of foreach and list.addrange

Tags: c#, linq

Does anyone knows what the LINQ code is for the following code?:

```
foreach (Bed bed in field.GetBeds())
{
    asparaguses.AddRange(bed.GetAsparaguses());
}
```

Comment: Why you need this? Your code is pretty straight-forward. Easy to understand and gets the job done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) to flatten nested lists

```
asparaguses.AddRange(field.GetBeds().SelectMany(bed => bed.GetAsparaguses()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `SelectMany` in order to *flatten* the *collection of collection*:

```
 asparaguses.AddRange(field
    .GetBeds()
    .SelectMany(bed => bed.GetAsparaguses()));
```